# sending JSON to address different then res

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, stream

I created a tiny express module.
this atm listening to `url` to run on localhost but is planned to be listening to  the `triggerURL:ListenPort` and run from external service.

**clientA**: the server should receive a call from a web page (`triggerURL`) and in response send the `JSON` object to `unity_url`.

**clientB**: A unity app will open be listening to `SendingPort`.

the thing is, while I have no problem to sent JSON to res and back to clientA, I'm not sure how to create a new writable stream and send the json to clientB using `resp` and `writable`.

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var triggerURL = ''; //i'll send an http request to this adress to trigger the action from server


var JSON = {
    item: "seeds",
    Answers: "5",
    richText: "<b>How can you reduce crop toxicity by turning plants upside down?</b><br/>Idea:<br/> Upside-down gardening is a hanging vegetable garden being the suspension of soil and seedlings of a kitchen garden to stop <b>pests</b> and blight,and eliminate the typical gardening tasks of tilling, weeding, and staking plants."
}
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var ListenPort = '8086'; // my port to recieve triggers
var SendingPort = '4046'; // which unity will listen to
var unity_url ='185.158.123.54:'+SendingPort; //fake IP, just for the example

//triggerURL
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    var resp = JSON.stringify(JSON);
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream();

    //res.json(JSON); //instead i wanna send it to unity_url;
});


//app.listen(ListenPort);
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to send a request to the target url. For example (using [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)).

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var JSON = {
    item: "seeds",
    Answers: "5",
    richText: "<b>How can you reduce crop toxicity by turning plants upside down?</b><br/>Idea:<br/> Upside-down gardening is a hanging vegetable garden being the suspension of soil and seedlings of a kitchen garden to stop <b>pests</b> and blight,and eliminate the typical gardening tasks of tilling, weeding, and staking plants."
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const unity_url ='185.158.123.54:4046'; //fake IP, just for the example

//triggerURL
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    var resp = JSON.stringify(JSON);

    fetch(unity_url, {
        method: 'post',
        body:    resp,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));

    res.status(200).send('OK');
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: thanks alot

and just to make sure, i can swap the '/' in the get function with the 'triggerURL' to set the url needed to invoke this function, correct?

Comment: That depends on what your `triggerURL` will look like. For example: `google.com/hello/world ` won't work, but `/hello/world` will.

Comment: well, the trigger also comes from an external url/IP (that's the clientA).
so where do I insert the IP so I can listen from there?

thanks again

Comment: The server will only ever listen "from" the IP at which it is located. You can't listen to connections made to another IP.

Comment: ahhh so in the same way I send the HTTP call to the unity, the trigger should send the call to where I'm listening.


so if this service is on another computer (remote service) and I need to call it from mine, do I need another service on my local machine that will then trigger the function on the remote service?